# Nested interpolation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I return an array of people from the database eg,

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jim',
    address: "123 Test Street",
    phone: "999999999"
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Tom',
    address: "123 Test Street",
    phone: "888888888"
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Harry',
    address: "123 Test Street",
    phone: "012345678"
}
]
```

my API allows me to select a partial person by setting the fields parameter

eg for this example,

```
&fields=id,name,address,phone
```

full url for this example,
    ?q=&fields=id,name,address,phone&id=1,2,3

I want to be able to dynamically generate a table based on the fields selected.

Something like this,

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="field in fields">[[ field.text ]]</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-repeat="field in fields">[[ person.[[ field.id ]] ]]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I interpolate the field.id so i can use to it select the key in person.

Edit, I have changed the interpolation characters to [[ & ]].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
<td ng-repeat="field in fields">[[ person.[[ field.id ]] ]]</td>
```

should be

```
<td ng-repeat="field in fields">[[ person[field.id] ]]</td>
```

Comment: Sorry should have said I've changed the interpolation characters as they interfere with twig.

Comment: Nice one, thanks mate.  ...I'm sure I tried array syntax, apparently not correctly!

Answer (score 1):

If working with newer versions of Angular, using curly brackets with the nested interpolation in square brackets will do the trick.

```
<table id="dynamicTable" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of Columns">{{col.column_name}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of Table">
            <td *ngFor="let col of Columns">{{row[[col.column_name]]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```